# PHP script sending two emails when there is a CC

Tags: php, email

The first email goes just to me, and the second is a duplicate to me and the CC.  There is no BCC.

emailing code:

```
$to = 'to@email.com';
$subject = 'Email';
$message = '<html><body><p>Hello from me!<br>';
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers = $headers . 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers = $headers . 'From: from@email.com' . "\r\n";
$headers = $headers . 'Reply-To: from@email.com' . "\r\n";
$headers = $headers . 'CC: cc@email.com' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

as you can see, there's only one CC, and one 'to' address.  I don't think it's the PHP.ini file:

```
[PHP]

engine = On

max_execution_time = 60     ;
 Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds 
max_input_time = 120    ;
 Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
memory_limit = 128M      ; 
Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (8MB)

post_max_size = 150M

default_mimetype = "text/html"

default_charset = "UTF-8"

file_uploads = On

upload_max_filesize = 150M

allow_url_fopen = On

user_agent="PHP"

default_socket_timeout = 60

cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1

cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
```

but there it is.
Why am I getting doubles?

Comment: Just to clarify, You send the email to yourself and a copy to yourself and a different email. Meaning, you should receive 3 mails in total (2 to one address and one to a different address). Do both address receive doubles, i.e. 4/2 instead of 2/1 emails? Are you sure your code does not run twice?

Comment: Nope.  Only the 'to' address gets doubles, and you'll see that it's listed only once.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a email handling library such as Swift Mailer. It handles this kind of thing much better than stringing your own headers together.

http://swiftmailer.org/